# Data type issue when exporting BIOS settings to CSV file

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-remoting, bios

I've run into an issue with exporting a string to a CSV file. My script is remotely getting BIOS settings from a Lenovo laptop using WMI queries and PowerShell. And I'm exporting the result to a CSV file. All the settings are exporting great, but "AvailableSettings" (BIOS setting options) seem to run into a type mismatch issue.

The output file looks like this:

```
CurrentSetting,"Status","AvailableSettings"
WakeOnLAN,"ACOnly","System.String[]"
EthernetLANOptionROM,"Enable","System.String[]"
```

The code:

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\ComputerList.txt

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $Computer = $Computer -replace "`t|`n|`r",""

    $Get_manufacturer = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer Win32_Computersystem).Manufacturer

    if ($Get_manufacturer -like "*lenovo*") {
        $manufacturer = "Lenovo"
        $selections = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer -Class Lenovo_GetBiosSelections -Namespace root\wmi
        $resultsLenovo = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer -Class Lenovo_BiosSetting -Namespace root\wmi | Where-Object CurrentSetting | ForEach-Object {
            $parts = $_.CurrentSetting.Split(',')
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                CurrentSetting = $parts[0]
                Status = $parts[1]
                AvailableSettings = $selections.GetBiosSelections($parts[0]).Selections.Split(',')
            }
        }

        $resultsLenovo | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\$Computer-BIOS-settings.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ',' -Encoding ASCII
    }
    Clear-Variable -Name manufacturer
}
```

There are more IFs for other manufacturers as well, but I haven't included them in this code snippet here.

When outputting the result to Out-GridView, it seems to be working just fine.

The result should be like this:

```
CurrentSetting,"Status","AvailableSettings"
WakeOnLAN,"ACOnly","Disable, ACOnly, ACandBattery, Enable"
EthernetLANOptionROM,"Enable","Disable, Enable"
```

Any ideas where do I messed up and how to sort the types out?

Comment: Remove `.Split(',')` where computing the `AvailableSettings` property. Maybe, use `Join` operator as ` -Join ','` instead.

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks a million, man! This worked. Please post your comment as an answer on this topic so that I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: @JosefZ By the way, how do these two methods differ (.Split(',') and Join) ?
I'm just wondering and trying to understand how the Split could mess it up.